# VirtualBox: Ubuntu guest-OS is sluggish on Mac host-OS, why?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, mac

I have created a `VM` using `VirtualBox v:6.0` that is running on top of a `macOS Mojava v:10.14.6`. The specs of the `VM` are as follow:

1. Guest-OS: `Ubuntu 16.04`
2. `8 GB` memory (half of the RAM)
3. `80 GB` storage (I have penalty)
4. `4 CPUs` for processors (out of 8)
5. `64 MB video memory` (out of 128)
6. `VMSVGA` graphic controller
7. `3D Acceleration` is Enabled
8. `Guess Additional CD image` is installed
9. Disabled animations
10. Removed unnecessary applications.

Yet, the `VM` is very sluggish, slow and isn't responsive as it should be.

what should I do ?

Comment: VBox on Mac is actually quite poor in comparison with VBox on Windows or Linux hosts.  The exact reasons are unknown.  VMWare Fusion tends to operate better with VMs on Mac, but it gets expensive.  The issue is VBox on Mac, and not really the guest OS at all (which means the issue is a host issue)

Comment: @ThomasWard [this thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=90446&start=45) seems to indicate that reverting to VBox 5.2 or "disabling HiDPI for the MBP retina display" fixes the issue. Also though, running a 3D (Unity) DE in a VM probably contributes. I bet using LXDE/XFCE would help too.

Comment: @ThomasWard : Downgrading to VirtualBox v:5.2 did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: As @ThomasWard confirmed, downgrading to VB 5.2 solved the problem. I was having issues with a particular program on my Win 10 client (32 bit) while the OS was okay. Host is a Macbook Pro Catalina. Created an account to thank you guys for the solution. God bless you all!

Comment: @You'reAGitForNotUsingGit I re-posted your comment as a community-wiki answer. Feel free to re-post it as a new answer using your account and then [ping me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), so I can remove my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using retina mac? If so, check out following: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315931/poor-performance-with-virtual-box-on-macbook-pro-2017/377866#377866

> Using second monitor for VM definitely will improve performance. Another workaround could be using remote connection to VM. I installed XRDP on Ubuntu VM on my MBP and using RDP client for access, no issues with performance.
>
> Please check following thread https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=90446&sid=391cad0521a6d2ce5848c78a38033893&start=45 There is another suggestion to use tool for Mac to use additional range of screen resolution, so your VM instance can run smooth on retina display

Answer (score 2):

*This answer was originally posted as a [comment to the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165719/virtualbox-ubuntu-guest-os-is-sluggish-on-mac-host-os-why#comment1943727_1165719) by [You'reAGitForNotUsingGit](https://askubuntu.com/users/518562/youreagitfornotusinggit).*

According to the forum thread [VirtualBox runs slow on MacBook Pro 2018 (screen refreshes slow)](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=90446&start=45), reverting to VirtualBox 5.2 or disabling HiDPI for the MBP retina display fixes the issue. Also though, running a 3D (Unity) DE in a VM probably contributes. I bet using LXDE/XFCE would help too.